# Digitally signing all identified powershell scripts in TFS Azure Devops

Tags: powershell, certificate, digital-signature

I am working on digitally signing of all powershell scripts in a folder from a repo in the TFS azure devops.

Using below command I can sign all the scripts under a specific folder:

```
signtool.exe sign /f MyCertificate.pfx /p Mypassword "C:\folder\repo\powershellscripts\*.ps1
```

So here I need to implement a logic in powershell script like if the `MyCertificate.pfx` is not found in the specified path the signing process should fail saying **required certificate not found to sign**.

I know the below code to check above executed code returns `0` success, `1` fail. But to check whether the certificate is present is the specified path or not I need help.

```
 if (! $?) {
       Write-Host "required certificate not found to sign" -ForegroundColor Red
       exit
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you do not specify a path for MyCertificate.pfx, so it must be present in the current workdirectory and so you can do

```
If (Test-Path .\MyCertificate.pfx){
signtool.exe sign /f MyCertificate.pfx /p Mypassword "C:\folder\repo\powershellscripts\*.ps1
}
Else {
write-error "required certificate not found to sign"
return #exit would cause to exit the process, what you probably not want to do
}
```

Comment: Yes, this looks great, thanks for that. But in my case I am keeping the MyCertificate.pfx in the securefiles in the TFS azure pipelines and downloading it in the Agent machine while running the pipelines. So I need to give the specified path.

Comment: based on your comment it makes more sense to check if the download succeeded

Comment: Yeah how to achieve that. Sorry I am asking for more but initially I was not sure, got an idea after your answer.

Comment: show me the code you use to download the certificate

Comment: I am using `Download Secure files` option in the **TFS Azure Release Pipelines**.  `steps:
- task: DownloadSecureFile@1
  displayName: 'Download secure file'
  inputs:
    secureFile: Certificate.pfx`

Comment: ok I see... sorry I have no experience with it